# sql injection code c# sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

this is my c# code

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["preconn"].ToString());

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from slab where salbn='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "'", con);

con.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.Read())
{
    TextBox12.Text = reader["basic"].ToString();
    TextBox13.Text = reader["hra"].ToString();
    TextBox15.Text = reader["trvl"].ToString();
    TextBox16.Text = reader["mdeca"].ToString();
    TextBox18.Text = reader["atnd"].ToString();
    TextBox20.Text = reader["tote"].ToString();
    TextBox21.Text = reader["salbn"].ToString();
}
con.Close();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["preconn"].ToString());

con.Open();

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("update slab set salbn = @salbn,basic = @basic,hra = @hra,trvl = @trvl,mdeca = @mdeca,atnd = @atnd,tote = @tote where salbn = @salb", con);

com.Parameters.Add("@salb", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);

com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salbn", TextBox21.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@basic", TextBox12.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hra", TextBox13.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trvl", TextBox15.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mdeca", TextBox16.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@atnd", TextBox18.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tote", TextBox20.Text);

com.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();

MsgBox("Updated Successfully");

}
```

this code is safe for sql injection...??

if no so please correct my code.
i am using sql server 2008.

Comment: Use *Prepared Statements* in the `select` queries also.

Comment: If you use parameterized queries and parameterized statements, you will be fine. That's why you should parameterized your first `SqlCommand` also. But your question seems doesn't fit here. Maybe in [CodeReview.SE] ?

Comment: Are your database field updated by your second query all of type text?

Comment: @Steve yes my salbn and basic column type is varchar(MAX) and all other are of type text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Parameters` on the `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` method, as you did in `Button1_Click`. Every query with ADO.NET will be safer using Parameters. I would do a `try/catch/finally` block for the connection close and `using()` scope for ado.net objects (remember the `using()` scope need to be in a object that implements `IDisposable` interface. It will remove your object from heap after execution, for sample:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["preconn"].ToString()))
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from slab where salbn=@salbn", con);
        com.Parameters.Add("@salb", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);

        con.Open();

        using(SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                TextBox12.Text = reader["basic"].ToString();
                TextBox13.Text = reader["hra"].ToString();
                TextBox15.Text = reader["trvl"].ToString();
                TextBox16.Text = reader["mdeca"].ToString();
                TextBox18.Text = reader["atnd"].ToString();
                TextBox20.Text = reader["tote"].ToString();
                TextBox21.Text = reader["salbn"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```